# Django: "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/samples'" during file upload via model

Tags: python, django, apache, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to push a sample file from admin page, via a model. Whole website works fine but I'm just getting this problem with this specific model.

> **Model**

```
class File(models.Model):
    area = models.OneToOneField(Actions, on_delete=CASCADE)
    sample_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='samples/', validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

> **Info**

`samples/` Directory relies in `BASE_DIR` of project.

> **Tried Fixes**

Read few articles, and got few ideas about permissions but my permissions are correct as well, folder is under www-data

`drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data   4096 Sep 24 17:53 samples`

I even tired changing permissions to `777` but didn't worked.

Am I missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions are perfect,if you get any issue like this then, any directory you must have to add in `setting.py`

and for permissions use `chown -R www-data /var/www/`